# How to fix a chipped countertop

Tags: kitchens, kitchen-counters, countertops

I recently remodeled my kitchen and while putting in the sink I had to remove it and i forgot to remove one clip and it ripped off a small piece of the laminate. So my question is if there is some way to put it back in a way that it should not be vissible? The only products I found was covering it with mixtures of solid colors not the way the countertops look so it will still be very vissible.                    Thanks

Comment: Do you have the piece? Superglue is your friend. You may need to sand the back of the chip a bit to get it to fit flush.

Comment: Super glue and maybe a touch of a color matching [seam sealer](http://www.cabinetparts.com/p/kampel-countertop-laminate-products-color-matched-caulk-SF00901?prclev=CMH63F4QHR35&gclid=CKqimKbjscsCFYqDfgodCO0NoQ). they do make different colors as you have found. This will help hide the backing if exposed on the chip and seal it so it will last longer. but get it glued down as @isherwood suggested +

Comment: @ isherwood @ Ed Beal Thanks. Do you mean specificly the brand Super glue? and yes I have the piece but was'nt able to push it in flat without any bumps left, do you think sanding could do the job with all curves in there?

Answer (score 1):

As Isherwood said super glue is a great option if you have the whole piece to put back in place. If the piece is lost or doesn't completely fit you may want to consider replacing a segment of the countertop.

When retailers make cuts from countertop materials there is often small pieces left over. Ask at your local hardware provider or better yet at the location you purchased your countertops. With a steady hand you can cut a straight line in the least visible area and replace the entire area.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking wood glue. Study the chip & see how it fits. The majority of the time they don't & won't drop-in they have to slide-in or be inserted. Since, they tear out & don't really "chip off".

Wood glue would fill in any missing fibers & also flow out around the torn edge. You can then also lightly hammer it inward & downward to re-seat it perfectly & re-marry it back into the microscopic layers you savagely violated.